# Сортировка списка по последнему столбцу python

Tags: python

Сортировка должна производиться следующим образом:
Сначала все элементы всех строк списка сортируются с помощью заданного ключа.
Затем строки переставляются таким образом, чтобы последние элементы были отсортированы с помощью заданного ключа.

```
data = [[6, 5, 4], [3, 2], [1]]
key = lambda x: x
res = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: И какая проблема?

Comment: "Затем строки переставляются таким образом, чтобы последние элементы были отсортированы с помощью заданного ключа." как это сделать

Comment: А что пробовали и где ошибку в вашем коде выдает? SO, вроде, не решебник задач без своих вариантов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
new_data1 = [sorted(i, key=key) for i in data] # сортировка внутренних списков 
new_data2 = sorted(new_data1, key=key) # сортировка главного списка
```

В одну строку можно так:

```
new_data = sorted([sorted(i, key=key) for i in data], key=key)
```

Comment: Неправильно, для ключа key = lambda x: -x не работает

Comment: У вас же написано в примере    key = lambda x: x.   Откуда вдруг взялся минус?